# Android Weird Null Object Reference on Button.setText(mText)

Tags: android, button, text, nullpointerexception

I'm stuck with the weirdest error I've ever got since I started programming. I'm setting a text to a button. Nothing complicated there!

I do it this way:

```
btnButton.setText(cell.getText());
```

btnButton exists since I've passed some others things to it before setting its text and cell.getText() is not null either since I can log the text in my console.

Still, I get this weird error:

```
03-31 14:58:35.407 24398-24398/ca.gggolf.agggolf.full E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: ca.gggolf.agggolf.full, PID: 24398
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6836)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4063)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3921)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3896)
                                                                        at ca.gggolf.agggolf.activities.fragments.AutoGridFragment.displayAutoGridBody(AutoGridFragment.java:467)
                                                                        at ca.gggolf.agggolf.activities.fragments.AutoGridFragment.createAutogridBody(AutoGridFragment.java:206)
                                                                        at ca.gggolf.agggolf.activities.fragments.AutoGridFragment.onCreate(AutoGridFragment.java:94)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Can someone help me fix this? It sometimes work but it depends from where in the application that I come from.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here's my whole code when creating the button. I assign it's width and initial text and then if the text should be truncated, I measure to make sure that my button will still fit in the size I gave it otherwise, I change it to textView.
It's when I set it back to normal after that it gives me the error.

```
Button btnButton = new Button(getActivity());
btnButton.setWidth(width);
btnButton.setText(cell.getText());
if(adjustedAutogrid.getColumn(indexCell).isTruncated()){
    btnButton.setText("…");
    btnButton.measure(0, 0);
    if(btnButton.getMeasuredWidth() > width){
        TextView btnText = new TextView(getActivity());
        btnText.setWidth(width);
        btnText.setText(cell.getText());
        cell.getCSS().applyToTextView(btnText);
        btnText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        btnText.setLines(1);
        layout.addView(btnText);
        break;
    }
    btnButton.setText(cell.getText());
    btnButton.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    btnButton.setLines(1);
}
```

And for those wondering from where it causes problem, well it's a bit complicated. I receive information through internet (an XML) that I convert to a table that I show. I must set the different cells the appropriate size and content. When I load what we call an AutoGrid coming from the XML, all my AutoGrid works except for one...

**Edit 2**
Everything works fine if I leave the text to the ellipsize symbol (…). It really is when i try to set the text again that it doesn't work..

Comment: How did you get your reference to `btnButton`? Did you use `findViewById()` or create it yourself? It looks like the button's `LayoutParams` is what is null.

Comment: Created it myself and haven't assigned any `layoutParams` because I don't see the use and as I said, the problem only occured when I come from certain places in my app

Comment: Looks like you are creating your buttons manually (and in the wrong place `Fragment.onCreate()`, should be done in `Fragment.onCreateView()`).

The view can't be layouted if you are not assigning LayoutParams with specification of width and height, this is how Android works. Therefore NullpointerException in ´ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width`

Comment: Please post your AutoGridFragment.java code .

Comment: See my edit for more details

Comment: And I thought about putting it back to onCreateView since I had to change it to fix something that finally we decided not to implement. But still, it all works except one case. With this very same code, I can show all the views I want

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems that if I set the text later with my button that everything is fine...

```
btnButton.setWidth(width);
btnButton.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
btnButton.setLines(1);
btnButton.setText(cell.getText()); // this line used to be the first one
```

If someone has an explanation, please fill free to enlighten me!